# hiding divs based on radio button selection using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two radio buttons for true and false. when I select the false I want to hide the orderaddress1 label and textbox. I used jquery It seems to not be working

this is my radio button view:

```
<div class="delivery">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeliveryChoice, "DeliveryChoice", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div>
                    <label>@Html.RadioButton("DeliveryChoice", true) Deliver my order to me</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>@Html.RadioButton("DeliveryChoice", false) I will pick up my order</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            </div>
```

view for text box and label:

```
<div class="Add1">
            <div class="form-group ">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderAdress1, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderAdress1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "box" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderAdress1)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#radio_button').click(function () {
            if ($("input[name='name']:checked").val() == false)
                $('.Add1').hide();
        });

        });

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You jQuery selectors are incorrect

You don't have an element with `id="radio_button"` so `$('#radio_button')` does not exist. Then inside that, you have `$("input[name='name']:checked")` but you don't have any inputs with `name="name"`

You script needs to be

```
// cache elements that you repeatedly reference
var address = $('.Add1');
// handle the change event of all radio button inside elements with class="delivery"
$('.delivery input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === 'true') {
        address.hide();
    } else {
        address.show();
    }
});
```

Refer [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfw0g2a7/1/)

Side notes:

1. Your `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeliveryChoice, ...)` is
   creating a label which will select the first radio button (unlikely
   to be what the use expects)
2. Your generating invalid html because both radio buttons have
   duplicate `id` attributes. Since you don't need the `id`, you can
   use `@Html.RadioButton("DeliveryChoice", true, new { id = "" })`
3. Its unclear why you divs have class names instead of `id`
   attributes. If you have multiple divs with `class="delivery"` and
   `class="Add1"` then the above script will need to be modified to use
   relative selectors.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

$('input:radio[name="name"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'false'){
        $('.Add1').hide();   }
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name=DeliveryChoice]').change(function () {
        $(this).attr('value') === 'False' ? $('.Add1').hide() : $('.Add1').show();
    });
});
```